# Deploying error on glassfish caused by WebFilter URL Pattern

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

i have this filter in my application:

```
package br.atualy.gestao.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import br.atualy.gestao.beans.RegraAcesso;
import br.atualy.gestao.beans.Usuario;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"*"}, filterName="RegraAcessoFilter")
public class RegraAcessoFilter implements Serializable, Filter{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpSession httpSession=req.getSession(true);
        Usuario usuarioLogado=(Usuario) httpSession.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");

        if(usuarioLogado!=null){
            //Vai pegar as regras do usuário logado e verificar a pagina q o cara ta tentando entrar.
            //Se achar a página nas permisões, e estiver pra bloquear gera, vai mandar o cara pro inferno... digo, pra uma pagina de erro.
            String paginaDestino = req.getServletPath();
            for(RegraAcesso regra : usuarioLogado.getRegrasAcesso()){
                if(paginaDestino.toLowerCase().startsWith(regra.getPagina().toLowerCase())){
                    if(regra.getBloqueioGeral()){
                        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/paginaErroPermissao.jsf");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response); 


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Whose goal is to be applied for every URL. It works as expected when deployed in Tomcat 7, but when deploying in Glassfish 4 it gives me this error, saying that the webPattern i used is wrong:

```
Exception while deploying the app [AtualyGestao] : Invalid url Patterns for [*]: {1}.. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter(servletNames=[], initParams=[], smallIcon=, description=, dispatcherTypes=[REQUEST], value=[], filterName=RegraAcessoFilter, largeIcon=, asyncSupported=false, displayName=, urlPatterns=[*])] on annotated element [class br.atualy.gestao.filters.RegraAcessoFilter] of type [TYPE]
Invalid url Patterns for [*]: {1}.. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter(servletNames=[], initParams=[], smallIcon=, description=, dispatcherTypes=[REQUEST], value=[], filterName=RegraAcessoFilter, largeIcon=, asyncSupported=false, displayName=, urlPatterns=[*])] on annotated element [class br.atualy.gestao.filters.RegraAcessoFilter] of type [TYPE]
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:419)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url Patterns for [*]: {1}.
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.annotation.handlers.WebFilterHandler.processAnnotation(WebFilterHandler.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.annotation.handlers.WebFilterHandler.processAnnotation(WebFilterHandler.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractWebHandler.processAnnotation(AbstractWebHandler.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.annotation.handlers.WebFilterHandler.processAnnotation(WebFilterHandler.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
    ... 75 more
]]
```

But if it's working with tomcat, why not in glassfish?
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What if you precede the `*` by `/` ?

Answer (score 1):

The filter should be for a valid path. A valid path starts with `/`. If you want/need to apply the filter for all URLs within your application, you should use `/*`.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/*"}, filterName="RegraAcessoFilter")
public class RegraAcessoFilter implements Serializable, Filter{
    /*
        current code...
    */
}
```